# Python3 utf8 codecs not decoding as expected in Docker ubuntu:trusty

Tags: docker, locale, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4, docker-registry

The following thing really bugs me, the version of python on my laptop and the version of python inside Docker's ubuntu:trusty image are printing different results with their codecs, what is the reason for that? 
For example, python3 on my laptop(ubuntu, trusty):

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Apr 14 2015, 14:16:55) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'\xe2\x80\x99','utf8')
'’'
>>>
```

python3 on Docker ubuntu:latest:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'\xe2\x80\x99','utf8')
'\u2019'
>>>
```

Can i make the python3 codecs on Docker's ubuntu:trusty decode b'\xe2\x80\x99' as '’'?

Comment: it seems like the image for ubuntu:latest simply doesn't have the character '’' which is '\u2019', so.... how do i install special character support to the os?

Comment: Right single quote? That's an old and pretty common character; it seems unlikely that support for it is missing in the OS. (It would be in the font you're currently using, if it was an issue.) I'm guessing it's more likely that Python 3.4.3 (or something about your settings) is converting that to a character for display, while 3.4.0 is just emitting the unicode notation for it. What happens if you run it in 3.4.0 on your local machine, or 3.4.3 on your Docker?

Comment: it doesn't look like a python problem, it seems like Docker's ubuntu:latest image doesn't have support for '\u2019' and a lot of other characters by default. i can't even paste the character into the docker container's terminal

Comment: That sounds like a locale setup issue. And I grabbed a copy of 3.4.0 for my OS X machine, and it displays `'’'` for me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a locale configuration issue. Python could be behaving differently in the two locations because the terminal sessions it's running in are configured differently.

Check your `locale` settings on your Ubuntu Docker machine to see that you're in a UTF-8 locale in your terminal session. In particular, see if you've been switched over to `C` for your `CTYPE`. (I've seen that on servers before, though don't know why it happens.) That could make a difference as to whether the Python console considers it a printable character and thus whether to display it as itself or an escape sequence. This would affect other terminal programs, too.

I was able to reproduce this behavior in Python 3.4.0 on OS X by fiddling with the locale settings.

```
[@ in ~]
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
[@ in ~]
$ python3.4
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 15 2014, 23:02:41)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'\xe2\x80\x99','utf8')
'’'
>>> quit()
[@ in ~]
$ LC_CTYPE=C python3.4
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 15 2014, 23:02:41)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'\xe2\x80\x99','utf8')
'\u2019'
>>> quit()
```

If it's your locale settings doing it, you need to either set up your rc files on the Docker Ubuntu instance to configure your locale to be the appropriate UTF-8 locale for you, or get your locale settings to propagate through SSH or whatever connection method you're using, in order to configure your remote terminal session there. Propagating your locale through connections may make more sense because it could fix it for other servers or accounts you connect to as well.

Comment: Thank you sir! That indeed seems to be the problem. Here's what i get from running locale:
    root@68e9072d6ec8:/# locale -a
    C
    C.UTF-8
    POSIX
    root@68e9072d6ec8:/# locale 
    LANG=
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
    LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
    LC_TIME="POSIX"
    LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
    LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
    LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
    LC_PAPER="POSIX"
    LC_NAME="POSIX"
    LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
    LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
    LC_ALL=

Answer (score 2):

The following illustrates what was happening and how to fix it:

```
root@df329ec1fe88:/# python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'\xe2\x80\x99','utf8')
'\u2019'
>>> exit()
root@df329ec1fe88:/# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
root@df329ec1fe88:/# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
root@df329ec1fe88:/# sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
root@df329ec1fe88:/# sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
root@df329ec1fe88:/# echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8" >> ~/.bashrc
root@df329ec1fe88:/# echo "export LANG=en_US.utf8" >> ~/.bashrc
root@df329ec1fe88:/# echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8" >> ~/.bashrc
root@df329ec1fe88:/# source ~/.bashrc 
root@df329ec1fe88:/# locale 
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
root@df329ec1fe88:/# python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'\xe2\x80\x99','utf8')
'’'
>>> exit()
root@df329ec1fe88:/#
```

You could then commit this container as a new image for future use or you could automate this process in your Dockerfile. Basically add the following lines:

```
RUN locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
RUN dpkg-reconfigure locales
RUN echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo "export LANG=en_US.utf8" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8" >> ~/.bashrc
```